# How many ids can be stored in a field array in firestore collection

Tags: arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking for a document design to store user ids that other users liked. My first approach (maybe not the best) is an array to store all users ids that liked someone. Something like:

```
/users/1
 - likedByUserIds: [1,2,3,4,5,...,1000,1000001,...]
```

I have to query by not liked users yet and show them first. So how many ids can be stored in a field array in firestore collection ? It can be many user ids from previous/past likes.

Comment: If you're using Android and if you want to check the size of a document against the maximum of 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes), check this library called [FirestoreDocument-Android](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreDocument-Android/tree/master/firestore-document).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution I found to avoid full search in firebase to perform `get users that haven't liked yet`.

- My users collection in firestore
- Add the user to redis `add('users',userId)`
- Add liked user to redis `zAdd('liked_users_${uid}',{value: userId})`
- Generate not liked yet `zDiffStore('not_liked_yet',['users','liked_users_${uid}']`
- Get not liked yet `zRange('not_liked_yet', 0, -1)`

It just worked !

Answer (score 0):

The number of elements of the array is not fixed.  The limit you will run into is the max total size of the document (1MB), which is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields).  The total size of the document is not going to be based on a single field.  It will be based on everything you put in it.  You can estimate the size of a document using information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size).

For lists of data that are not bounded within the limits of a single document, it's better to store the items as individual docments in a collection.  There is no bound to the number of documents in a collection.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. How can I design documents/collections to query/get all users that I haven't liked yet ? I can't see it how. Can you explain to me please?

Comment: Not possible to do at scale in Firestore without reading all the documents and subtracting out those that have been "seen".  You can only query for data that exists. If you can't tag a document as unseen in its fields, you can't query for it.

Comment: What about design a document as /likedusers which does have an array of likedByUserIds[] ? So I can query by users isn't in array. Is it that bad? Can you provide some solution/workaround that works firestore ?

Comment: If you want opinions about your designs, I suggest posting to reddit and explain in more detail.

Comment: Appreciate that ! I found a solution mixing redis geo diff + firestore. I'm gonna post it here soon.

Comment: Just post something here that fix the problem in a decent way.

Answer (score 0):

Just what @Doug stated, "there's a maximum total size for a document: 1MB". There's also a Firestore single-field index exemption limit which is 200. A [single-field index](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/index-overview#single-field_indexes) stores a sorted mapping of all the documents in a collection that contain a specific field. Each entry in a single-field index records a document's value for a specific field and the location of the document in the database.

Additionally, there's a [single-field index exemptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#single-field_index_exemptions) that you can exempt a field from your automatic indexing settings by creating a single-field index exemption. An indexing exemption overrides the database-wide automatic index settings. Since we need to hold that information in memory of every process that could handle a write to your database, and compare the incoming write to this list of exemptions. This creates a need for both memory management and latency impact.

For further reference, you can check this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54613365/16531380) about Firestore single-field index exemption limit.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. How can I design documents/collections to query/get all users that I haven't liked yet ? I can't see it how. Can you explain to me please?